# Accessing parent Fragment layout from child Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs

Good day to all. I can't figure out how to access parent Fragment layout from child Fragment. Let's say I have main activity with tabs defined in ActionBar. Each Tab is Fragment. Now in one of those tabs I want to use tabs again (sticked to bottom this time). I'm able to create needed layout using classic TabHost. Each of these sub-tabs will be operated by same Fragment class - literally it should be plain ListView with almost same data from database, it will differ by one field only (full list, "visited" items and "not visited").

So here's my parent PlanFragment, which is placed on of tabs of main Activity. It has TabHost and populates 3 Tabs using PlanListFragment:

```
public class PlanFragment extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "PlanFragment";

    public static final String TAB_FULL = "full";
    public static final String TAB_VISITED = "visited";
    public static final String TAB_NOT_VISITED = "not_visited";

    private View mRoot;
    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private int mCurrentTab;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plan, container, false);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        setupTabs();
        return mRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(mCurrentTab);
        updateTab(TAB_FULL, R.id.tab_plan_full);
    }

    private void setupTabs() {
        mTabHost.setup();
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_FULL, R.string.label_tab_plan_full,
                R.id.tab_plan_full));
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_VISITED,
                R.string.label_tab_plan_visited, R.id.tab_plan_visited));
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_NOT_VISITED,
                R.string.label_tab_plan_unvisited, R.id.tab_plan_not_visited));
    }

    private TabSpec newTab(String tag, int labelId, int tabContentId) {
        TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(getActivity().getString(labelId));
        tabSpec.setContent(tabContentId);
        return tabSpec;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if(TAB_FULL.equals(tabId)) {
            updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_plan_full);
            mCurrentTab = 0;
            return;
        }
        if(TAB_VISITED.equals(tabId)) {
            updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_plan_visited);
            mCurrentTab = 1;
            return;
        }
        if(TAB_NOT_VISITED.equals(tabId)) {
            updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_plan_not_visited);
            mCurrentTab = 2;
            return;
        }
    }


    private void updateTab(String tabId, int placeholder) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm.findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null) {
            PlanListFragment plan = new PlanListFragment();
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(PlanListFragment.TAG, tabId);
            plan.setArguments(params);
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(placeholder, plan, tabId)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

}
```

Here's layout with TabHost:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_plan_full"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <include layout="@layout/plan_list" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_plan_visited"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <include layout="@layout/plan_list" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_plan_not_visited"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <include layout="@layout/plan_list" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

plan_list.xml included on each tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally PlanListFragment in which I plan to setup CursorAdapter for database based on parameter passed from parent Fragment. How do I access ListView here?

```
public class PlanListFragment extends ListFragment {

    protected static final String TAG = "PlanListFragment";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle params = getArguments();
        Log.d(TAG, params.getString(TAG));
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now during my further investigations I found following scheme to work. Key parameter moved to "tag" attribute of  call in layout. If there are any drawbacks please advice.

PlanFragment.java

```
public class PlanFragment extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "PlanFragment";

    public static final String TAB_FULL = "full";
    public static final String TAB_VISITED = "visited";
    public static final String TAB_NOT_VISITED = "not_visited";

    private View mRoot;
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plan, container, false);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        setupTabs();
        return mRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    private void setupTabs() {
        mTabHost.setup();
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_FULL, R.string.label_tab_plan_full,
                R.id.tab_plan_full));
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_VISITED,
                R.string.label_tab_plan_visited, R.id.tab_plan_visited));
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_NOT_VISITED,
                R.string.label_tab_plan_unvisited, R.id.tab_plan_not_visited));
    }

    private TabSpec newTab(String tag, int labelId, int tabContentId) {
        TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(getActivity().getString(labelId));
        tabSpec.setContent(tabContentId);
        return tabSpec;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    }

}
```

fragment_plan.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/tab_plan_full"
                android:tag="plan_full"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                class="com.example.collector.PlanListFragment" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/tab_plan_visited"
                android:tag="plan_visited"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                class="com.example.collector.PlanListFragment" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/tab_plan_not_visited"
                android:tag="plan_not_visited"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                class="com.example.collector.PlanListFragment" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

plan_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

PlanListFragment.java

```
public class PlanListFragment extends ListFragment {

    protected static final String TAG = "PlanListFragment";

    public PlanListFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plan_list, container, false);

        Log.d(TAG,getTag());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In child fragment try to access the parent fragment like this:

```
ParentFragment frag = ((ParentFragment)this.getParentFragment());
frag.sendbutton.setVisibility(View.Visible).invalidate();
```

Here "sendbutton" is the Button in parent fragment. You should use invalidate() in child fragment to refresh the view if required.

Comment: What if we want to get string in a child fragment without using a reference of public static data type?

Comment: you can't access the datatype if it is not public in parent fragment from child fragment